# counting the '0's in a string in assembly

Tags: c, string, assembly, x86, att

I have a little program written with c and assembly. the principle is simple: "count the '0's in a a string given by main.c

so for `test0 str0ing 0` it should return `3` because there's 3 '0's in the string
the function itself is made in x86 asm with AT&T syntax, i am given a pointer to the string via C. both main.c and the asm is linked via header file.

this is my code so far and the problem is that it always returns 0. it never reaches conditional jump to increment %eax(to be returned)

// C

```
#include "asm.h"

char string[] = "2a0 a0 ";
char *ptr1 = string;

int main(){
    
    printf("\nthere are : %d %s in :%s", zero_count(), "0s", string);
    printf("\nstring address is: %p\n", ptr1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

// x86asm

```
    .global ptr1

.section .text
    .global zero_count          #func()
    

zero_count:

    # prologue
    pushl %ebp              # save these previous stack frame pointer
    movl %esp, %ebp         # the stack frame pointer for function
    
    # save registers
    #pushl $ebx             # needs to be pushed out of stack when used
    #pushl %esi             # needs to be pushed out of stack when used
    #pushl %edi             # needs to be pushed out of stack when used
    
    # function body
    movl ptr1, %ecx         # moves the value of ptr1 to ecx
    movl $0, %eax           # cleans eax with 0
                    
    # loop start
    loop_beginning:
        cmp $0, (%ecx)
        je end
        
        # compare to 'o'
        cmp $48, %ecx       # 48 is "0" in the asci table
        je if_0
        
        increment_pointer:
            addl $1, %ecx
            jmp loop_beginning
        
        if_0:
            addl $1, %eax
            jmp increment_pointer
            
    end:
    #popl %edi              # needs to be popped when used
    #popl %esi              # needs to be popped when useds
    #popl %ebx              # needs to be popped when used
    
    # epilogue
    movl %ebp, %esp         # restore the previous stack pointer("cleaner" the stack)
    popl %ebp               # restore the previous stack frame pointer
    ret                     #w returns
```

i apolagize for using global variables in advance, i know it's not good but I'm still learning to use the stack

Comment: `cmp $48, %ecx` - ECX holds a pointer, not a character value.  Since you want to check for both `0` (terminator) and `'0'` (ASCII digit), you should `movzbl` load it into a register like EDX.

Comment: Also note that `cmp $48, (%ecx)`  is a dword, not a byte compare.  Use `cmpb $48, (%ecx)` instead.

Comment: @fuz: Any idea if GAS would accept a patch to error on `cmp $0, (%ecx)` as ambiguous operand-size, like it does for `mov $0, (%ecx)`?  This does seem to come up not infrequently.  BTW, I had a look for existing duplicates, but no luck.  I'm sure there have been multiple Q&As where the pointer was being compared instead of the pointed-to data, though, hence only posting a comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not sure.  Perhaps with a new option to the `.att_syntax` directive?  IIRC the LLVM assembler might actually reject amiguous operand sizes.

Comment: @fuz but isn't the ecx going to be filled with a 16 bit address? and i just compare what is the address pointing to with ()

Comment: @fuz: Yeah, `clang -c` says `error: ambiguous instructions require an explicit suffix (could be 'cmpb', 'cmpw', 'cmpl', or 'cmpq')`.  I think the right approach would be to add a backwards-compat option (or directive) for building old bad source code with new GAS.  To give a benefit to beginners, you want to checking to be on by default.

Comment: @skidils It's a 32 bit address, but that doesn't really matter here. The thing is, you didn't tell the assembler what size datum the address in `ecx` refers to.  So it assumes it's a dword (32 bit value), but you want a byte (8 bit value).  You need to use the `b` suffix on the instruction to explicitly chose an 8 bit operand size.

Comment: i had no issue with using cmp rather than cmpw, cmpl. gcc didn't gave any errors or warnings. is this any kind of issue with the logic behind the loop? am i doing the loop right?

Comment: @fuz`using addb ptr1, %ecx gave out segmentation fault

Comment: @skidils `addb ptr1, %ecx` should not assemble.  Also, `ptr1` is a 32 bit datum, so the `b` suffix is incorrect here.  `l` should be used to indicate a 32 bit datum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by switching the cmp to cmpb worked in this string. but i still don't know why. would this operation also worked if this was an int[]?

```
    .global ptr1

.section .text
    .global zero_count          #func()
    

zero_count:

    # prologue
    pushl %ebp              # save these previous stack frame pointer
    movl %esp, %ebp         # the stack frame pointer for function
    
    # save registers
    #pushl $ebx             # needs to be pushed out of stack when used
    #pushl %esi             # needs to be pushed out of stack when used
    #pushl %edi             # needs to be pushed out of stack when used
    
    # function body
    mov ptr1, %ecx          # moves the value of ptr1 to ecx
    movl $0, %eax           # cleans eax with 0
                    
    # loop start
    loop_beginning:
        cmpb $0, (%ecx)
        je end
        
        # compare to 'o'
        cmpb $48, (%ecx)        # 48 is "0" in the asci table
        je if_0
        
        increment_pointer:
            addl $1, %ecx
            jmp loop_beginning
        
        if_0:
            addl $1, %eax
            jmp increment_pointer
            
    # movl (%ecx), %eax
    
    end:
    #popl %edi              # needs to be popped when used
    #popl %esi              # needs to be popped when useds
    #popl %ebx              # needs to be popped when used
    
    # epilogue
    movl %ebp, %esp         # restore the previous stack pointer("cleaner" the stack)
    popl %ebp               # restore the previous stack frame pointer
    ret                     #w returns
```

Comment: No of course it would not.  You would have to adjust the data size to `l` for a 32 bit value and change `addl $1, %ecx` to `addl $4, %ecx` to walk through the array in 4 byte steps.